# Prevent vim :make from changing the current working directory?

Tags: perl, vi, vim

### Synopsis:

When calling vim's make command, it changes the current working directory (cwd) to the directory of the current file.  It then runs the makeprg from there.  I want to prevent the make command from changing the cwd, and instead call the makeprg from the directory of the parent vim instance

### Example:

I have the following standard perl project hierarchy

```
    project/
      lib/
        My/
          Module/
            Foo.pm
```

My PERL5LIB is set to

```
    PERL5LIB=':lib'
```

In my .vimrc I have

```
    compiler perl
    set makeprg=perl\ -c\ %
```

I edit my module using vim from the root project level:

```
    /path/to/project$ vim lib/My/Module/Foo.pm
```

In vim :pwd works as expected:

```
    :pwd
    "/path/to/project"
```

Also calling !perl -c works as expected, finds my project lib, and displays the result in a shell window:

```
    :!perl-c %
    OUTPUT:
       perl -c lib/My/Module/Foo.pm
       lib/My/Module/Foo.pm Syntax ok
```

However :make returns an error

```
    :make
    "Can't open perl script lib/My/Module/Foo.pm : No such file or directory"
```

Setting makeprg to pwd shows the problem

```
    :set makeprg=pwd
    :make
    "/path/to/project/lib/My/Module"
```

So before make runs makeprg it is changing to the directory of the current file, which is why perl can't find 'lib/.../Foo.pm' there.

Is there any way to prevent make from doing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally.  Do you have `autochdir` set?  (`:se acd?`)  What autocmds do you have?  (`:au`, you can ignore the ftdetect stuff)

Comment: autochdir was not set, but going through :au found the problem!  I have eclim installed for Java development, and there is an eclim global var that triggers QuickFixLocalChangeDirectory() to be called on :make.  Toggling this global var solved the problem.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Vim's :make command is changing the current working directory, and autochdir is not set, a plugin may have added an autocommand to the QuickFixCmdPre set.  One plugin that does this is eclim, which calls the QuickFixLocalChangeDirectory() function if g:EclimMakeLCD is set to 1.

Use :au to find all the autocommands in your current configuration, paying particular attention to entries for QuickFixCmdPre and make.